# Non-resolvable parent POM: 1.5.17.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from https://repo.spring.io/snapshot

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I have tried many solutions like force updating maven dependency , checking the maven plugin configuration, everything seems ok but still the dependency cannot be resolved. So definitely there is an issue with my configuration/settings which i am unable to find.

I have configured the network proxy in the settings.xml as well as in STS network configuration console and i see https://repo.spring.io/snapshot is opening from the embedded browser that STS provides.
Error is : 'Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.17.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from https://repo.spring.io/snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.17.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from/to spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot): Failed to authenticate with proxy and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM'

**settings.xml** in C:\Users\my_user.m2\repository is pointed in STS and it has proxies configured

**POM.xml**

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.myTeam.microservices</groupId>
<artifactId>Demo Project</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Demo Project</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.17.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <start-class>com.myTeam.microservices.Demo Project.Demo ProjectApplication</start-class>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <cxf.version>2.7.14</cxf.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SLF4J logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.wss</groupId>
        <artifactId>xws-security</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>10.2.0.4.0</version> -->
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.novell</groupId>
        <artifactId>ldap</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ldap.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>

                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdls/sample.wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdlOption>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdls/sample.wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdlOption>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdls/sample.wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Why are you using SNAPSHOT versions instead of released version like `1.5.17.RELEASE` or `1.5.18.RELEASE` or even better `2.0.7.RELEASE` etc. See https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.springframework.boot%20AND%20a:spring-boot-dependencies&core=gav

Comment: no such reason.. ok. let me check using release version

Comment: it worked like a charm! I always thought it was something regarding proxy.. but had no idea of difference between a snapshot and a released version. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: So you can now remove the repository definitions from your pom file cause you usually consume only releases from Central...

Comment: @Reese remember to use "RELEASE" versions for your project. These versions are stable, while "SNAPSHOT" aren't necessarily.

Comment: yes.. got it. Thanks much for your help!